# How to increase memoir table of contents spacing between appendix and its hyphen?

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, xpatch, abnt, abntex2

After patching (manually, i.e, directly editing memoir's code), this:

[image]

It should look like this:

[image]

I tried to patch the memoir using `xpatch`. This patch I did would work if it was finding the correct code, but `xpatch` says is does not find the code to patch:

```latex
\documentclass[
12pt,
]{abntex2} % memoir is loaded internally by the `abntex2` class
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\chapternumberlineappendixpatch}[1]{%
\chapternumberlinehook{#1}%
\chapternumberlinebox\@tempdima{\@chapapp@head\@cftbsnum #1~~\@cftasnum~~}%
\@cftasnumb~}%

\patchcmd{\@chapter}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{appendix}{\protect\chapternumberline{\thechapter}\f@rtoc}
}{}{\addcontentsline{toc}
  {appendix}{\protect\chapternumberlineappendixpatch{\thechapter}\f@rtoc}}{
  \message{Chapterformat patch for chapternumberline could NOT
  be applied because its code was not found!^^J ^^J^^J^^J^^J^^J^^J^^J^^J^^J^^J}
  \xshowcmd\@chapter
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{Some}

    \begin{apendicesenv}
        \chapter{Other}
    \end{apendicesenv}

\end{document}
```

This the `memoir` code:

```latex
File: memoir.cls
2926:     \ifanappendix
2927:       \addcontentsline{toc}{appendix}{%
2928:         \protect\chapternumberline{\thechapter}\f@rtoc}%
2929:       \memappchapinfo{\thechapter}{\f@rtoc}{\f@rhdr}{#2}%
2930:     \else
```

It should stop calling that `\chapternumberline` and call my custom `\chapternumberlineappendixpatch` function with increased the space around the hyphen:

```latex
\newcommand{\chapternumberlineappendixpatch}[1]{%
\chapternumberlinehook{#1}%
\chapternumberlinebox\@tempdima{\@chapapp@head\@cftbsnum #1~~\@cftasnum~~}%
\@cftasnumb~}%

File: memoir.cls
2926:     \ifanappendix
2927:       \addcontentsline{toc}{appendix}{%
2928:         \protect\chapternumberlineappendixpatch{\thechapter}\f@rtoc}%
2929:       \memappchapinfo{\thechapter}{\f@rtoc}{\f@rhdr}{#2}%
2930:     \else
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it by patching smaller fragments:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,]{abntex2} % memoir is loaded internally by the `abntex2` class
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpretocmd{\l@appendix}{\def\@chapapp@extrahyphenspaces{~}}
{\message{^^J^^JChapterformat patch 1 for chapternumberline could SUCCESSFULLY!^^J}}
{\message{^^J^^JChapterformat patch 1 for chapternumberline could NOT be applied!^^J}}

\xpretocmd{\l@chapter}{\def\@chapapp@extrahyphenspaces{}}
{\message{^^J^^JChapterformat patch 2 for chapternumberline could SUCCESSFULLY!^^J}}
{\message{^^J^^JChapterformat patch 2 for chapternumberline could NOT be applied!^^J}}

\patchcmd{\chapternumberline}{\@cftasnum}{%
  \@chapapp@extrahyphenspaces%
  \@chapapp@extrahyphenspaces%
  \@cftasnum%
}
{\message{^^J^^JChapterformat patch 3 for chapternumberline could SUCCESSFULLY!^^J}}
{\message{^^J^^JChapterformat patch 3 for chapternumberline could NOT be applied!^^J}}

\patchcmd{\chapternumberline}{\@cftasnumb}{%
  \@cftasnumb%
  \@chapapp@extrahyphenspaces%
  \@chapapp@extrahyphenspaces%
}
{\message{^^J^^JChapterformat patch 4 for chapternumberline could SUCCESSFULLY!^^J}}
{\message{^^J^^JChapterformat patch 4 for chapternumberline could NOT be applied!^^J}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{Some}

    \begin{apendicesenv}
        \chapter{Other}
    \end{apendicesenv}
\end{document}
```

---

Before patching it:
[image]

After patching it:
[image]